# After upgrading spring-cloud-starter-vault-config to 4.1.0 from 3.1.0 and upgrading spring boot to latest version authentication is failing for vault

Tags: spring-vault

These are my vault configuration

```
spring.cloud.vault.enabled=true
spring.cloud.vault.uri: pointing to valut server
spring.cloud.vault.connection-timeout: 5000
spring.cloud.vault.read-timeout: 15000
spring.cloud.vault.authentication: KUBERNETES
spring.cloud.vault.kubernetes.role: test
spring.cloud.vault.kubernetes.kubernetes-path: kubernetes
spring.cloud.vault.kubernetes.service-account-token-file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
spring.config.import: vault://secret/cc-test1/test
```

this the error I am getting when we start the application `[RequestedSecret [path='secret/cc-test1/test', mode=ROTATE]] Lease [leaseId='null', leaseDuration=PT0S, renewable=false] Cannot retrieve VaultToken from authentication chain`
note: application working properly with version 3.1.0 issue we are facing after upgarding

anything we are missing here.
thanks in advance